# devise 1.4.7 does not generate routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have been using devise for sometime now.  Suddenly, I have no routes for devise controllers when I run 'rake routes'. What happened? Do I need to revert to an earlier version of devise? If so, how do I accomplish this?

routes.rb:

```
NbbApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
  resources :categories
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"} 
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your routes.rb file.

Comment: NbbApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :products
  resources :categories

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}

  root :to => "home#index"

end

Comment: Which version of rails? Which version of devise?

Comment: If you do rake routes in console with your routes file looking like that, what comes up?

Comment: I would suggest downgrading the devise version (go to 1.4.6) and run your tests and see when it breaks. Continue this process until your tests pass.  Then checkout the devise changelog  (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc) to see if you can pinpoint why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
bundle exec rake routes
```